# c++ fork / std::thread and boost::timed_join

Tags: multithreading, c++11, fork, boost-thread, stdthread

I've got a program which is analysing a number of files (up to 10000). 
Platform is AMD64 with a unix operating system. Language is c++.

The program is currently forking the main process for every file (until a limit is reached, then it waits until a child is finished).
The child is starting a boost::thread to execute the analysing functionality and then does a boost::timed_join on the boost::thread it created.

So, i've got some questions now.

1. Would it be reasonable to replace the fork with a more lightweight option? i'm not sure how much of a performance / memory gain this could be, i read somewhere on stackoverflow that fork isn't that expensive on unix.
2. How would i implement the killing of the thread which is doing the anlysis?
   start 2 threads, one executes the analysis and the other one is waiting and if the first one isn't finished after a certain amount of time, the second is killing the first? is there a more elegant way of doing this? 
   if this is the option of choice, how do i kill another thread? getting the native handle and then pthread_kill() ?
3. if keeping the fork mechanism is adviceable:
   i've thought about replacing the boost::threads with std::threads, how would i replace the boost::timed_join ? letting the child process sleep for some time and then kill the thread would be a way of doing it but if the thread is finished before the time ends (which will happen all the time), the child would still be sleeping until the time is over -> overhead.

any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: creating a new process is more heavyweight than creating a new thread, so not doing that will give advantage in terms of used resources. On the other hand, if the forked process crashes then the other processes are not affected, which might be not the case with threads.

Answer (score 1):

I came across [AFIO](http://rrsd.com/blincubator.com/bi_library/afio/) ([docs](https://ci.nedprod.com/job/Boost.AFIO%20Build%20Documentation/Boost.AFIO_Documentation/), [code](https://github.com/BoostGSoC13/boost.afio)) today. It is an aspiring Boost candidate built on ASIO and Boost.Thread.

> AFIO is a linear scalable, batch, chainable, asynchronous closure execution engine extending ASIO and Boost.Thread specialised as a portable asynchronous file i/o implementation library.

This might streamline your async file processing.

Note that this would not fork other OS processes, but instead use threads or ASIO Proactor thread-like constructs instead. It will probably consume less system resources, but is more crash prone (as commented by @Ashalynd)

Comment: I as a Boost.AFIO author would have to disagree with this recommendation :) If you want to process 10,000 files as fast as possible I'd actually recommend you launch a thread per file which opens the file, maps it into memory and reads it from the memory map (if the file is greater than 64Kb). Threads are very cheap on any recent OS, and memory maps give the kernel maximum latitude to make best use of your RAM and storage i/o queue depth. AFIO can do all the above of course, but it's probably overkill for your needs - writing it directly is not hard.

Comment: I'll also add as one of the Boost.Thread maintainers that you really want to avoid ever mixing threads and forks. Choose one OR the other. Mixing them introduces a lot of complexity for Boost.Thread i.e. performance killing overhead. Forks alone are pretty fast nowadays, but threads have more predictable complexities and overheads. Forks are just so very convenient though. Finally, there should be a thread timed_join function in the C++ 11 STL, so simply turn on C++ 11 on your toolchain.